# Measuring probability density function for a device with two stochastic sources

Tags: probability-distributions, gaussian

We have a time delay element that given an input pulse it generates an output pulse after time T_nom. T-nom is the average time it takes for the device to output a pulse. Due to the device's mismatching characteristics the delay has stochastic nature and follows a Gaussian distribution as following:

$$F(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \ \sigma_{mis}}e^{-\frac{(t-T_{nom})^2}{2\sigma_{mis}^2}}$$

where $\sigma_{mis}$ is the device's mismatch standard deviation. In addition to the device's mismatching we have also what's called a random noise or jitter which is inevitable for the device. This jitter, which additionally perturbs the delay time, also follows a Gaussian distribution function with the standard deviation $\sigma_{jit}$.

What I want now is to include the effect of the jitter in the function F(t) and come up with a compact model to fully describe the stochastic behavior of the device. But how?

Comment: just replace $\sigma_{mis}^2$ with $\sigma_{mis}^2+\sigma_{jit}^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hinted in the comments, if you assume that the jitter is independent from the device's mismatching, the total time delay $\Delta T$ is given by $$ \Delta T = T_{mis}+T_{jit}$$
Where $T_{mis}\sim \mathcal N(T_{nom},\sigma_{mis}^2)$ and $T_{jit}\sim \mathcal N(0,\sigma_{jit}^2)$.
Now, since $T_{mis}$ and $T_{jit}$ are assumed to be independent, [you can deduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables) that their sum $\Delta T$ is also normally distributed with mean $T_{nom}$ and variance $\sigma_{mis}^2+\sigma_{jit}^2$. So the PDF of $\Delta T$ is
$$f_{\Delta T}(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(\sigma_{jit}^2+\sigma_{mis}^2)}}\cdot \exp\left({-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{t-T_{nom}}{\sqrt{\sigma_{jit}^2+\sigma_{mis}^2}}\right)^2}\right) $$